# What's the correct function name convention inside of powershell modules?

Tags: powershell

I am creating a powershell module and following the Verb-Noun naming conventions for the functions that I exported.

e.g.

```
function Do-Something() {
    sleep 10
}
```

Importing the modules works as expected... BUT if I import that module as a custom object.

```
$myObject = Import-Module MyModule -AsCustomObject
```

Then try to access the function, I get a parse error:

```
PS > $myObject.Do-Something()
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At line:1 char:22
+ $myObject.Do- <<<< Something()
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

I don't understand.  Does this mean that I can't use the '-' in methods that belong to objects?
I have noticed that .NET objects and other PSObjects do not have '-' in their method names.
I haven't figured out a way to escape it yet either... but even so, that would be messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
     $myObject."Do-Something"()

Comment: If it's a matter of a scripting convenience, you can alias it: $myObject | add-member -membertype scriptrproperty -name "DoThis" -value {$this."do-something"()}

Comment: I'm marking this one "correct" because nothing with Microsoft is ever clear... :-)
Aliasing it is a good workaround to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$myObject."Do-Something"()
```

Functions usually are written in Pascal case ( DoSomething ) or with `_` ( underscore) between the words ( do_something ).

Comment: In powershell, the very strong convention is verb-noun.

Comment: @Mike Shepard - for functions? I don't think so.

Comment: The convention is where I am confused.... Verb-Noun IS the convention, but Methods on objects use Pascal case without the dash.  so when writing a module, which convention do I pick?  the Method one or the "powershell" one?

The quotes do work though... so I think you answered my question... but perhaps there is another question here.  And that is... "Aren't these conventions contradictory since there is an option to load a module as an object?" :-)

Comment: @Randy James - I don't see a need to use the Verb-Noun convention on functions. On cmdlets, yes, but not on functions. Pascal case is what I have been following, and makes it easier since that is the convention in C# as well.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this issue come up before.  You might consider adding an alias inside the module to allow DoSomething (along with any other functions in your module).